# ChickenCounter Program and ChickenCounter Tester with Java

Tags: java

```
// The countChicken() method should count the number of occurrences of the word chicken (or some other word) in the string passed to it.
// Use recursion to accomplish this (countChicken() should call itself whenever "chicken" is found).
// Make this class flexible by passing the word you want to search for as a parameter to the constructor.  If
// nothing is passed to the constructor (there is no parameter), then the search word should be "chicken".
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class ChickenCounter
{
   //Create two constructor methods here, one with no parameter and one with one parameter
    private String word;
    private int length;
    private int x;
    public ChickenCounter()
{
  word = "chicken";
  length = 7;
  x = 0;
}
public ChickenCounter(String z)
{
 word = z;
 length = word.length();
 x = 0;
}
// The parameter bigString below should contain the long string that you want to find the word chicken in
public int countChickens(String bigString)   
{
    if(bigString.length() <= length)
    {
        if(bigString.equals(word))
        {
            return 1;
        }

        else
        {
            String temp = bigString.substring(x, length-1);//line that is highlighted when given the error 
            if(temp.equals(word))
            {
                bigString = bigString.substring(x, bigString.indexOf(word)) + bigString.substring(bigString.indexOf(word)); //dont know if this is the correct syntax of the method indexOf()
                return countChickens(bigString) + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                x++;
                return countChickens(bigString); //this line is also part of the problem
            }
        }
    }
      return 0;
   }
}


import static java.lang.System.*;


public class ChickenCounterTester
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ChickenCounter counter = new ChickenCounter();

    System.out.println(counter.countChickens("itatfun")); //0 <--what it supposed to output

    System.out.println(counter.countChickens("itatchickenfun")); //1

    System.out.println(counter.countChickens("chchickchickenenicken")); //3

    System.out.println(counter.countChickens("chickchickfun")); //0

    System.out.println(counter.countChickens("chickenbouncetheballchicken")); //2       


    //pass the word to search for to the object

     counter = new ChickenCounter("java");

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println(counter.countChickens("jjajavavaavaisfun")); //3 

    System.out.println(counter.countChickens("I want some jajavava")); //2

}
```

}

Ouput:
0
1
2
0
7

1
2

I keep on getting a index out of bounds error that says its out of range -1. The program is about trying to find a certain word in a string given to me. My teacher is using the word as an example for this code. He wants to go thru each line of code and find the word chicken if we find it add it to the counter variable if not remove it and go thru the string again and try it find the word again.

Comment: What if the string doesn't contain your word?

Comment: You have declared same object counter twice this is the main problem in your code. Another one is you have passed null while declaring counter object and you are trying to access object properties. so, length of object will be 0 and length-1 = -1 and index out of bound has been displayed

Comment: first if condition is incorrect if(bigString.length() <= length)

Comment: Seems like you had Mr. Smith too?

Answer (score 0):

Your professor wants you to use recursion to count the number of occurrences of a word in a string. Your current `countChickens` method does not contain the correct logic. It should be something like the following:

```
public int countChickens(String bigString){
      if(bigString.contains(word)){
        return 1 + countChickens(
         bigString.substring(
          bigString.indexOf(word)+word.length()));

      }else{
       return 0;
     }
  }
```

Comment: but bigString isn't the word that I'm looking for. Its the string that contains the word in it that you are searching thru

Comment: @CMC17 try the method I provided.

Comment: My program is based in bluej

Comment: it works but not the output that i want but thank you for your help so far

Answer (score 0):

```
counter.countChickens("chchickchickenenicken")
```

For this input how you get 3 as output. In this input only one **chicken** word is available. That is the reason you didn't get a correct output. Otherwise *@Eduardo Dennis* **countChickens method** works correct.